# Transaction question

Tags: transaction

I have a question.

c stands for Commit, a stands for Abort, T is a transaction (db Transaction)

Is the following sentence true?

```
either c or a belong to T
```

In my opinion the sentence is true since if you have Abort you cannot Commit...and also the opposite is true.

So if you have c you cannot have a, a mutual exclusion.

Sorry to bother you but my teacher said I made a mistake

Thanks

Comment: What does your teacher say?

Comment: I think 'belong' is a wrong word here. It usually says that transaction ends with commit or rollback. Group of DML statements belong to transaction; commit/rollback is a way to finish transaction.

Comment: What about the case when you abort part of the transaction and commit the rest?

Comment: @a1ex07 I think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @Raihan - that's not how atomicity works.

Comment: @JNK there is such thing as defining save points along a transaction and rolling back to one of them before commiting the transaction.

Comment: @Raihan - that's really just committing a smaller transaction.

Comment: @JNK - by aborting the remainder of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Moved from comment to answer**

I think 'belong' is a wrong word here. It usually says that transaction ends with commit or rollback. Group of DML statements belong to transaction; commit/rollback is a way to finish transaction...*emphasized text*